# Display recylerview Data with Array of CustomLists

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I'm a bit stuck on the following.

I'm using Retrofit and RxJava2, and I managed to get a `List<List<CustomModel>>` by using `Observable.zip` and `return Arrays.asList(list1, list2, list3);` it now looks like the following:

[list1,list2,list3]

I can access the lists and print each individual item using:

```
                for (List<CustomModel> b : customModel) {
                    for (customModel c : b) {
                        Print INDIVIDUAL ITEMS
                        Log.d("id: ", c.getId());
                        Log.d("name: ", c.getName());
                        Log.d("symbol: ", c.getSymbol());
                        Log.d("rank: ", c.getRank());
                    }
```

but I can't manage to send the data to my Custom adapter using:

```
   recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), b);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Only gives me the latest list on the array but not the past as they get overwritten when passing the data to my recyclerview.

What will be the best way to display all 3 lists inside the recyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `CustomModel` is your model class. `RecyclerAdapter` is your Class which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>`, where `RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder` is your Class inside `package RecyclerAdapter` which extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

```
private List<CustomModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;


recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); 
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(modelList);

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Whenever new data comes, **don't create new adapter & assign to recyclerview**. Just add to the existing list & notify the adapter. New items will appears.

```
for (List<CustomModel> customModels : customModelLists) {
    modelList.addAll(customModels);
}

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Personally I find this link helpful: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Thank you very much for your Guidance, 

I have now corrected the problem and I now understand how the recyclerview  and lists works now.

My issue s exactly as you described, I was creating a new adapter and not adding the data to the list.

All I had to do is to notify the recyclerView to add the data.